# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value int to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to multiple the value with 100 in my sql statement.
But it showing error like Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 0.0035 to data type int.

And i know that the value is in varchar. But i want to multiple with 100

this is my original query code:

```
@WalCalc as VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'CAST(   (ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0)) AS varchar(50)) AS ''Coupon'',
```

and the converted query

```
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'CAST(   (ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0) * 100) AS Decimal(18,3)) AS ''Coupon'',
```

Please some one help me

Comment: What is the Data Type of DI.Coupon?

Comment: varchar @dinesh

Comment: Please provide some sample data for the `Coupon` column.

Comment: Coupon 
0.0702,
0.0218,
0.008,
0.0169,
0.0259
0.0067
0.0134,
0.0156,
0.0183,
0.0252,
0.0351

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be converting the `Coupon` column to a decimal *first*, and then multiplying by 100:

```
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'ISNULL(CAST(DI.Coupon AS Decimal(18, 3)), 0.0) * 100 AS ''Coupon'',
```

Comment: What is the error?  Is there any leading or trailing whitespace in the `Coupon` column?

Comment: No whitespace in the column @ Time biegeleisen

Comment: @AravindhanR I have tested the snippet in my answer with string literal coupon decimal values, and it seems to work in all cases.  It would be helpful to see some actual data here.  I will leave this answer up so long as you cannot provide data for which this would not work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

First `CAST` your Coupon value to `NUMERIC` and do the Multiply:

```
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'CAST(   (ISNULL(CAST(DI.Coupon AS NUMERIC(18,3)),0) * 100) AS Decimal(18,3)) AS Coupon
```

This is What I Executed:

```
SELECT CAST((ISNULL(CAST('0.0702' AS NUMERIC(18,5)),0) * 100) AS Decimal(18,3)) AS Coupon
```

**Output**:

```
Coupon
7.020
```

Comment: it showing error as Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: If it's fine then accept the answer. It will help someone.

Comment: @DineshDB Hi Dinesh, may I ask why you chose to do two casts instead of just one?

Comment: @DineshDB can your send me your mail id to this aravindhan32@outlook.com. In feature if i have any doubts i can contact you.

Comment: @AravindhanR, you just execute the two Queries, and you should understands the difference: SELECT CAST((ISNULL(CAST('0.0702' AS NUMERIC(18,5)),0) * 100) AS Decimal(18,3)) AS Coupon
SELECT ISNULL(CAST('0.0702' AS NUMERIC(18,3)),0) * 100 AS Coupon

Comment: @AravindhanR, Sure I'll send my mailId

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'CAST((ISNULL(DI.Coupon,0) ) AS Decimal(18,3)) * 100 AS ''Coupon'',
```